# itunes software update ignore isn't working

Tags: itunes, safari, software-update, leopard, itunes-store

I have OSX 10.5.6 and iTunes 10.4.1 on my laptop. I turned off the software update for iTunes, but every time I click on a song, I get a notification that says

> iTunes requires Safari 4.0.3 or later to be installed to use the
>   iTunes Store with iTunes. Use Software Update to download and install
>   the latest version of Safari.

I'm not trying to use the iTunes store, so I'm not sure why this is popping up. I'd prefer not to update Safari because I never use that browser. Suggestions?

Comment: How did you turn off the updates in itunes?

Answer (score 1):

Since iTunes uses web kit and html to work in the store, you might actually need it for the software to function.

If the app still works for your needs, you can safely ignore the message, but if you don't use that browser, why not just update it and let iTunes be happy?